# Ошибка при обработке многомерного массива при помощи foreach

Tags: php

Привет. Работаю с многомерным массивом(прислан от клиента в виде JSON, декодирован в многомерный массив):

```
{
  "segment": [
    {
      "flight": [
        {
          "arrival": "MSQ",
          "trip_class": "Y",
          "technical_stops": [],
          "arrival_date": "2017-12-15",
          "operated_by": "B2",
          "equipment": "735",
          "duration": 60,
          "arrival_time": "11:20",
          "arrival_timestamp": 1513326000,
          "departure_timestamp": 1513322400,
          "operating_carrier": "B2",
          "aircraft": "Boeing 737-500",
          "baggage": "1PC23",
          "number": 844,
          "marketing_carrier": "B2",
          "delay": 0,
          "departure_time": "09:20",
          "local_departure_timestamp": 1513329600,
          "departure": "KBP",
          "local_arrival_timestamp": 1513336800,
          "departure_date": "2017-12-15"
        },
        {
          "arrival": "ZIA",
          "trip_class": "Y",
          "technical_stops": [],
          "arrival_date": "2017-12-15",
          "operated_by": "B2",
          "equipment": "738",
          "duration": 85,
          "arrival_time": "19:30",
          "arrival_timestamp": 1513355400,
          "departure_timestamp": 1513350300,
          "operating_carrier": "B2",
          "aircraft": "Boeing 737-800",
          "baggage": "1PC23",
          "number": 973,
          "marketing_carrier": "B2",
          "delay": 405,
          "departure_time": "18:05",
          "local_departure_timestamp": 1513361100,
          "departure": "MSQ",
          "local_arrival_timestamp": 1513366200,
          "departure_date": "2017-12-15"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "flight": [
        {
          "arrival": "MSQ",
          "trip_class": "Y",
          "technical_stops": [],
          "arrival_date": "2018-01-18",
          "operated_by": "B2",
          "equipment": "738",
          "duration": 85,
          "arrival_time": "21:30",
          "arrival_timestamp": 1516300200,
          "departure_timestamp": 1516295100,
          "operating_carrier": "B2",
          "aircraft": "Boeing 737-800",
          "baggage": "1PC23",
          "number": 974,
          "marketing_carrier": "B2",
          "delay": 0,
          "departure_time": "20:05",
          "local_departure_timestamp": 1516305900,
          "departure": "ZIA",
          "local_arrival_timestamp": 1516311000,
          "departure_date": "2018-01-18"
        },
        {
          "arrival": "IEV",
          "trip_class": "Y",
          "technical_stops": [],
          "arrival_date": "2018-01-18",
          "operated_by": "B2",
          "equipment": "733",
          "duration": 60,
          "arrival_time": "22:30",
          "arrival_timestamp": 1516307400,
          "departure_timestamp": 1516303800,
          "operating_carrier": "B2",
          "aircraft": "Boeing 737-300",
          "baggage": "1PC23",
          "number": 847,
          "marketing_carrier": "B2",
          "delay": 60,
          "departure_time": "22:30",
          "local_departure_timestamp": 1516314600,
          "departure": "MSQ",
          "local_arrival_timestamp": 1516314600,
          "departure_date": "2018-01-18"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

В массиве есть массив с ключом **segment**: в нём может быть 1 и больше вложенных массивов(в данном случае - 2).
В каждом сегменте есть вложенный массив с ключом **flight**, который может содержать 1-3 вложенных массива.

В конечном итоге, мне нужно работать только с массивами внутри **flight**, для чего я делаю так:

```
foreach($proposal['segment'] as &$segment) {
    foreach($segment['flight'] as &$flight) {
```

И это работает. Правда, только в том случае, если существует только 1 вложенный в **segment** массив. Если в сегменте 2 массива, то я получаю ошибку:

> Undefined index: departure

Как это может быть? Я ведь беру каждый сегмент поштучно и работаю с ним под именем `$segment`, а затем беру каждый `$segment['flight']` и работаю с ним под именем `$flight`; Всё ведь правильно.

Comment: Почему у вас в `foreach` используется  `&$flight`?

Comment: @Борис потому, что приставка `&` позволяет изменять значения ключей этого массива внутри цикла.

Comment: Вообще непонятно как и зачем массив segment содержит много одинаковых ключей

Comment: @Artur не содержит он одинаковых ключей, ключи там во вложенных объектах.

Comment: не удается воспроизвести проблему. все нормально вроде. Добавьте [mcve]

Comment: декодируете вы ведь через `json_decode(..., true)` в ассоциативный массив?

Comment: @Artur ну вот [как-то так](https://i.gyazo.com/54f09a1cdaf956cc85c08bfa45553dd6.png). Когда отправляется segment только с одним вложенным массивом(то есть, только одним индексом - 0), то всё ок. Если отправить segment c двумя ключами - 0 и 1, как на скриншоте выше - то будет ошибка.

Comment: Всё, нашёл ошибку. В нескольких десятках мегабайт логов нашёл Warning `Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000`.

Answer (score 1):

Доброе утро.

Попробуйте, пожалуйста, такой способ

```
foreach ($arr as $val){
    foreach($val as $key=>$value){
        if($key !== "flight")
            continue;
        else
            $newarr[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была не с foreach, а с лимитами PHP:

> FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Unknown: Input
>   variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars
>   in php.ini.

Странно только, почему алгоритм какое-то время работал как следует, а потом начал вбрасывать эти ошибки.